# flutter image_picker can't access camera real device, how to solve?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

Helo guys, i'm using flutter image_picker on real device i can't access camera, but if running with debugging it's run as well, in the first time i'm using camera i don't know what is forget with my function, so it's wrong or not? let see code below:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File? _image;
  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    final imageFile =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxWidth: 600);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(imageFile!.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(" this pict${_image}");
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.black,
          onPressed: _takePicture,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: _takePicture,
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          _image == null
              ? Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text('No Image'),
                  ),
                )
              : Image.file(_image!),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@fernnandoptr/how-to-use-camera-in-flutter-flutter-camera-package-44defe81d2da

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to add Permission for IOS (Info.plisht) and for Android in Manifest